# flag 0 or 1 on a foreach loop php

Tags: php, validation, count

I have a query always results to two rows. How can i flag the first row equal 1 and the second is 0?

here is the code

```
$rows  =  array(
               array('number' => 1),
               array('number' => 2)
               );
$i=1;
foreach($rows as $r) {
    if($i == 1) {
      $i = 1;
    } else {
      $i = 0;
    }
    //Flag first row as 1
    //Flag second row as 0;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Setting $i to 1 if it already has that value doesn’t make that much sense, hm?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by flagging?

Comment: just to track the first row variable $i is equal to 1 and the second row is $i is equal to 0

Comment: with the current code, `$i` is always 1, so no on the second row $i is not 0. Will you only ever have two rows? What should the value of `$i` be for others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [Modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%`:

```
foreach($rows as $index => $r) {
  $i = ($index % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
  echo "<br/>" . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you say query always return two rows then try this:

```
foreach($rows as $key=>$r) {
if($key=="0") {
  $i = 1;
} else {
  $i = 0;
}
//Flag first row as 1
//Flag second row as 0;
}
```